# Fetch columns and their associated values from log table and update Article table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two Log tables S38T1 and S39T1. I have made a query to join them to get the relevant data (sample data is shown at the end) as described below:

Query:

```
SELECT S38T1.datreg, S38T1.procid , S38T1.ma_table, S38T1.username,
        S39T1.termname, S39T1.oldvalue, S39T1.newvalue
FROM S38T1 inner join S39T1 on S39T1.datreg = S38T1.datreg
AND S38T1.procid = S39T1.procid
AND S38T1.username Like 'ALKA'
Where S39T1.termname IN('shortl62','partwght','suwght','suvol','suheight','sulength','suwidth','huheight','hulength','huwidth','huqty')
order by S38T1.datreg ASC
```

On basis of 'datreg' field I have to find the latest date. then

1. fetch S39T1.termname having values ('shortl62','partwght','suwght','suvol','suheight','sulength','suwidth','huheight','hulength','huwidth','huqty')
2. fetch equivalent S39T1.oldvalue for ('shortl62','partwght','suwght','suvol','suheight','sulength','suwidth','huheight','hulength','huwidth','huqty')
3. also fetch equivalent S39T1.newvalue for ('shortl62','partwght','suwght','suvol','suheight','sulength','suwidth','huheight','hulength','huwidth','huqty')
4. IN last step I have to update the table Article using the values fetched in above steps. The Article table have same columns i.e. ('shortl62','partwght','suwght','suvol','suheight','sulength','suwidth','huheight','hulength','huwidth','huqty')

I'll appreciate your suggestions.

```
DATA:

###     datreg         |procid| ma_table| username | termname | oldvalue |newvalue|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-09-13 16:35:57.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | huheight | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 
2014-09-13 16:35:57.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | hulength | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 
2014-09-13 16:35:57.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | huqty    | 0.200000 | 0.200000 | 
2014-09-13 16:35:57.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | huwidth  | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 
2014-09-13 16:35:57.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | partwght | 1.000000 | 1.000000 | 
2014-09-13 16:35:57.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | shortl62 | 81       |  81      |  
2014-09-13 16:35:57.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suheight | 0.000000 | 5.000000 | 
2014-09-13 16:35:57.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | sulength | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 
2014-09-13 16:35:57.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suvol    | 0.100000 | 0.100000 | 
2014-09-13 16:35:57.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suwght   | 1.000000 | 1.000000 | 
2014-09-13 16:35:57.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suwidth  | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 
2014-09-13 16:38:07.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | huheight | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 
2014-09-13 16:38:07.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | hulength | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 
2014-09-13 16:38:07.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | huqty    | 0.200000 | 0.200000 | 
2014-09-13 16:38:07.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | huwidth  | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 
2014-09-13 16:38:07.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | partwght | 1.000000 | 1.000000 | 
2014-09-13 16:38:07.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | shortl62 | 81       |   81     | 
2014-09-13 16:38:07.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suheight | 5.000000 | 5.000000 | 
2014-09-13 16:38:07.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | sulength | 0.000000 | 26.000000|
2014-09-13 16:38:07.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suvol|   | 0.100000 | 0.100000 | 
2014-09-13 16:38:07.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suwght   | 1.000000 | 1.000000 | 
2014-09-13 16:38:07.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suwidth  | 0.000000 | 30.000000|
2014-09-13 16:39:17.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | huheight | 0.000000 | 14.000000|
2014-09-13 16:39:17.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | hulength | 0.000000 | 30.000000|
2014-09-13 16:39:17.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | huqty    | 0.200000 | 0.200000 | 
2014-09-13 16:39:17.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | huwidth  | 0.000000 | 27.000000|
2014-09-13 16:39:17.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | partwght | 1.000000 | 1.000000 | 
2014-09-13 16:39:17.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | shortl62 |       81 |    81    | 
2014-09-13 16:39:17.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suheight | 5.000000 | 5.000000 | 
2014-09-13 16:39:17.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | sulength | 26.000000| 26.000000|
2014-09-13 16:39:17.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suvol    | 0.100000 | 0.100000 | 
2014-09-13 16:39:17.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suwght   | 1.000000 | 1.000000 | 
2014-09-13 16:39:17.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suwidth  | 30.000000| 30.000000|
2014-09-13 16:43:03.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | huheight | 14.000000| 14.000000|
2014-09-13 16:43:03.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | hulength | 30.000000| 30.000000|
2014-09-13 16:43:03.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | huqty    | 0.200000 | 3.000000 | 
2014-09-13 16:43:03.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | huwidth  | 27.000000| 27.000000|
2014-09-13 16:43:03.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | partwght | 1.000000 | 0.300000 | 
2014-09-13 16:43:03.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | shortl62 | 81       |   81     | 
2014-09-13 16:43:03.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suheight | 5.000000 | 5.000000 | 
2014-09-13 16:43:03.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | sulength | 26.000000| 26.000000|
2014-09-13 16:43:03.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suvol    | 0.100000 | 0.100000 | 
2014-09-13 16:43:03.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suwght   | 1.000000 | 1.000000 | 
2014-09-13 16:43:03.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suwidth  | 30.000000| 30.000000|
2014-09-13 17:03:56.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | huheight | 32.500000| 32.500000|
2014-09-13 17:03:56.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | hulength | 22.000000| 22.000000|
2014-09-13 17:03:56.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | huqty    | 4.000000 | 4.000000 | 
2014-09-13 17:03:56.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | huwidth  | 36.500000| 36.500000|
2014-09-13 17:03:56.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | partwght | 0.000000 | 0.342000 | 
2014-09-13 17:03:56.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | shortl62 |   86069  |  86069   |
2014-09-13 17:03:56.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suheight | 30.500000| 30.50000 |
2014-09-13 17:03:56.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | sulength | 5.000000 | 5.000000 | 
2014-09-13 17:03:56.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suvol    | 5414.0000| 5414.0000| 
2014-09-13 17:03:56.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suwght   | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 
2014-09-13 17:03:56.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suwidth  | 35.500000| 35.500000|
2014-09-13 17:19:47.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | huheight | 0.000000 | 31.500000|
2014-09-13 17:19:47.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | hulength | 0.000000 | 50.000000|
2014-09-13 17:19:47.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | huqty    | 0.200000 | 0.200000 | 
2014-09-13 17:19:47.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | huwidth  | 0.000000 | 40.000000|
2014-09-13 17:19:47.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | partwght | 1.000000 | 1.320000 | 
2014-09-13 17:19:47.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | shortl62 |     76   |    76    |
2014-09-13 17:19:47.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suheight | 0.000000 | 30.000000|
2014-09-13 17:19:47.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | sulength | 0.000000 | 39.000000|
2014-09-13 17:19:47.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suvol    | 0.100000 | 0.100000 | 
2014-09-13 17:19:47.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suwght   | 1.000000 | 1.000000 | 
2014-09-13 17:19:47.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | suwidth  | 0.000000 | 12.000000|
2014-09-13 17:28:26.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | huheight | 0.000000 | 20.000000|
2014-09-13 17:28:26.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | hulength | 0.000000 | 26.000000|
2014-09-13 17:28:26.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | huqty    | 0.200000 | 6.000000 | 
2014-09-13 17:28:26.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | huwidth  | 0.000000 | 38.500000|
2014-09-13 17:28:26.00 | 1932 | Article | ALKA     | partwght | 1.000000 | 0.302000 |
```

Comment: What is the structure of Article and which columns do you want updated? It seems like all you need to do is take your SELECT query and put it inside an UPDATE statement.

Comment: The article table has these columns

shortl62, partwght, suwght, suvol,  suheight, sulength, suwidth, huheight, hulength, huwidth, huqty

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand. Your Article table has the columns  that are similar to the rows of your query? This may make more sense if you show us what you expect the Article table to look like after the query runs successfully. I think you may want to look at [pivot tables](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx)

Comment: Actually The query is based on two log tables. These log tables have information about Article table and its columns which were updated by a background program.

The Log table has column 'ma_table' which has table name 'Article' as its value.

The Log table also has column 'termname' which has column-names/feilds of 'Article' table as its values.

Comment: Log table has two more columns 'oldvalue' and 'newvalue' which shows the old value and new value (after updating) for the field listed under 'termname' column and for the table listed in 'ma_table' column.

The structure of Article table is:

Create Table Article (
int shortl62, float huheight, float hulength, float huqty, float huwidth, float partwght, float suheight, float sulength, float suwght, float suvol )

Comment: Now I have to improve my query listed above. I have to fetch the table name from the log-data above and find its column-name and then  fetch its new value and update Article table.

I have to do this task in run time by reading log table , fetching Article table and its columns from it and then saving it into Article table ...

I hope now its give you a clear picture.. What I meant :)

Comment: Any thoughts #Guillaume ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I resolved it by this way: 

With cte1  ( datreg, procid, ma_table, username, termname, oldvalue, newvalue, RowNum)
 As (
                    SELECT S38T1.datreg, S38T1.procid , S38T1.ma_table, S38T1.username,
                            S39T1.termname, S39T1.oldvalue, S39T1.newvalue, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY S38T1.datreg  ORDER BY S38T1.datreg)
                    FROM S38T1 inner join S39T1 on S39T1.datreg = S38T1.datreg
                    AND S38T1.procid = S39T1.procid
                    AND S38T1.ma_table = 'Article'
                    where (S39T1.termname IN('partwght','suwght','suvol','suheight','sulength','suwidth','huheight','hulength','huwidth','huqty') and S39T1.newvalue !=S39T1.oldvalue)

            ),

 cte2 (Maxdatreg, shortl62)
AS (            
            SELECT S38T1.datreg,  S39T1.oldvalue as Shortl62
            FROM S38T1 inner join S39T1 on S39T1.datreg = S38T1.datreg
            AND S38T1.procid = S39T1.procid
            AND S38T1.ma_table = 'ARticle'      
            Where S39T1.termname IN('shortl62')

            )
SELECT * FROM cte1 inner join cte2 ON cte2.Maxdatreg = cte1.datreg 
order by cte2.Maxdatreg

then using Cursor to read records in the resultset and update the table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Actually The query is based on two log tables. These log tables have information about Article table 
 and its columns which were updated by a background program. The Log table has column 
'ma_table' which has table name 'Article' as its value. The Log table also has column 
'termname' which has column-names/feilds of 'Article' table as its values. 


Log table has two more columns 'oldvalue' and 'newvalue' which shows the old value and new value 
(after updating) for the field listed under 'termname' column and for the table listed in 
'ma_table' column. The structure of Article table is: Create Table Article ( int shortl62, 
float huheight, float hulength, float huqty, float huwidth, float partwght, float suheight, 
float sulength, float suwght, float suvol ) 


Now I have to improve my query listed above. I have to fetch the table name from the log-data 
above and find its column-name and then fetch its new value and update Article table. I have to 
do this task in run time by reading log table , fetching Article table and its columns from it 
and then saving it into Article table ... I hope now its give you a clear picture.. What I meant :)


Any thoughts ?
```